# Why is the reverse function in Haskell not working?

Tags: recursion, reverse

So I'm am supposed to return a list of Int using recursion in haskell.  I am creating the list correctly but the numbers in the list are out of order.  I tried using the reverse function to get the correct output but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.  This is the function and what the output is supposed to be

numlist 0

[0]

numlist 4

[0,1,2,3,4]

numlist (-5)

program error: illegal argument

This is my function

```
numList :: Int -> [Int]
numList n | n < 0 = error "program error: illegal argument"
          | n == 0 = reverse([n])
          | otherwise =  n:numList(n-1)
```

Comment: Reversing a single-element list won’t do anything (`[n] == reverse [n]`). Can you think of a way to start at zero and add instead of subtracting?

Comment: that's a good idea, i think i will try that